# In Json array output short by product price ASC and DESC

Tags: php

Need rearrange ( ASC / DESC ) by product price with it's variation price.
Like I have 3 product id ,also each product have 2 or 4 variation with their price details.

Like :

```
product 1 { variation 1 => price : 100 , variation 1 => price : 200 }
product 2 { variation 3 => price : 150 , variation 4 => price : 50 }
product 3 { variation 5 => price : 250 , variation 6 => price : 800 }
```

So , it will rearrange for ( DESC ) by

```
product 3 { variation 5 => price : 250 , variation 6 => price : 800 }
product 1 { variation 1 => price : 100 , variation 1 => price : 200 }
product 2 { variation 3 => price : 150 , variation 4 => price : 50 }
```

because , for product 3 have the biggest price than product 2 .

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "Product list found.",
    "product_data_list": [
        {
            "product_id": "42",
            "product_variations": [
                {
                    "details": {
                        "variation_id": "88",
                        "variation_image": "http://192.168.1.1",
                        "variation_price": "100.00"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "details": {
                        "variation_id": "89",
                        "variation_price": "50.00"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "product_id": "54",
            "product_variations": [
                {
                    "details": {
                        "variation_id": "128",
                        "variation_image": "http://192.168.1.1/",
                        "variation_price": "4000.00"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "details": {
                        "variation_id": "129",
                        "variation_image": "http://192.168.1.1/",
                        "variation_price": "200.00"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "product_id": "55",
            "product_variations": [
                {
                    "details": {
                        "variation_id": "133",
                        "variation_image": "http://192.168.1.1/RGB_api/DUMMY",
                        "variation_price": "1600.00"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "details": {
                        "variation_id": "134",
                        "variation_image": "http://192.168.1.1/RGB_api/DUMMY",
                        "variation_price": "1200.00"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "details": {
                        "variation_id": "135",
                        "variation_image": "http://192.168.1.1/",
                        "variation_price": "2600.00"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We expect you to show what you already tried, and not just “drop off your requirement” here. This is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PHP` `usort`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Basically, `usort($array, "cmp")` will execute the callback function `cmp($a,$b)` for every combination `($a,$b)` of 2 elements from `$array`, placing `$a` above `$b` when it returns `1`, placing `$a` below `$b` when it returns `-1`, and doing nothing when it returns `0`. Note that the sorting algorithm uses deduction, so it will only need to compute a subset of all possible pairs `($a, $b)`.

Here i use a comparison function `cmp2` to sort each variation of a product to get the highest price at index `0`, and than i use `cmp1` to sort the products by their highest variation price:

```
usort($data->product_data_list, "cmp1");
print_r($data->product_data_list);

function cmp1($a, $b){
    usort($a->product_variations, "cmp2");
    usort($b->product_variations, "cmp2");
    if ($a->product_variations[0]->details->variation_price == $b->product_variations[0]->details->variation_price) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->product_variations[0]->details->variation_price > $b->product_variations[0]->details->variation_price) ? -1 : 1;
}

function cmp2($a, $b){
    if ($a->details->variation_price == $b->details->variation_price) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a->details->variation_price > $b->details->variation_price) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => 1
    [message] => Product list found.
    [product_data_list] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [product_id] => 54
                    [product_variations] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [details] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [variation_id] => 128
                                            [variation_image] => http://192.168.1.1/
                                            [variation_price] => 4000.00
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [details] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [variation_id] => 129
                                            [variation_image] => http://192.168.1.1/
                                            [variation_price] => 200.00
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [product_id] => 55
                    [product_variations] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [details] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [variation_id] => 135
                                            [variation_image] => http://192.168.1.1/
                                            [variation_price] => 2600.00
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [details] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [variation_id] => 133
                                            [variation_image] => http://192.168.1.1/RGB_api/DUMMY
                                            [variation_price] => 1600.00
                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [details] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [variation_id] => 134
                                            [variation_image] => http://192.168.1.1/RGB_api/DUMMY
                                            [variation_price] => 1200.00
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [product_id] => 42
                    [product_variations] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [details] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [variation_id] => 88
                                            [variation_image] => http://192.168.1.1
                                            [variation_price] => 100.00
                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [details] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [variation_id] => 89
                                            [variation_price] => 50.00
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Sir, Thanks for your valuable reply . Can you please give me a small note on what is $a and $b ??

Comment: It help me a lots . Thanks once again .

Answer (score 0):

You use PHP tag but there isn't your PHP logic.
Can you put here to check what to do ?

Otherwise, a solution can be decode json in PHP and sort it in PHP logic.
After that you can encode PHP variable to json.
See :

- https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php